# Get month from mssql DateTime Object with php

Tags: php, sql-server, datetime

When I print the Array I get this

```
[CreatedDate] => DateTime Object ( [date] => 2013-03-20 00:00:00 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => America/Denver )
```

I'm trying to pull the month from the date, so far no luck. Been doing a combination of the below code and got a date to return but it was 12/31/1969 which is not in my database

```
$month = date("m",($row['CreatedDate']));
$month = date("m",($row['CreatedDate.date']));
$month = date("m",($row['date']));
```

Comment: You are close....Google "PHP mktime".

Comment: What is the code that creates this object? As the answer below suggests, this may already be a PHP date object.

Comment: I just did a print_r on the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever produced the DateTime object already has what you need. You just need to call `format()` to get the month:

```
echo $object->format('m');
```